# WebApi Switch Connectionstring related on HeaderValue - Request is null

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

We have different Customers and each of them own a Database.

the client send an Request with an HttpHeader DatabaseOwner:Samsung

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DatabaseOwner", "Samsung");
```

In my ApiController i would like that my Context is based on that Value and connects to the correct Database

```
public class AuthController : ApiController
    {
        public CmpContext db { get; set; }

        public AuthController(): base()
        {

            db = new CmpContext(VcsCmpConnectionstring.GetCMPConnectionString(this.Request));
        }

        // GET api/Auth
        public IQueryable<DealerModel> GetDealer()
        {

            return db.Dealer;
        }

 public static string GetCMPConnectionString(HttpRequestMessage request) 
        {

            string returnvalue;

            if (request.Headers.Contains("DatabaseOwner"))
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder ConnStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMPContext"].ConnectionString);
                ConnStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = "vcs_cmp_" + request.Headers.GetValues("DatabaseOwner").First();
                returnvalue = ConnStringBuilder.ToString();
            }
            else 
            {
                throw new MissingFieldException("Header DatabaseOwneris null");
            }

            return returnvalue;
        }
```

**When i try to get this.Request it is always null**

When is Request access able or is there a better way to switch between Databases?

Greetings from Bavaria
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Request object is only initialized after APIController's Initialize function is called. So you cannot access Request before base.initialize is called. Try doing this:

```
public class AuthController : ApiController
    {
        protected override void Initialize(
        System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {            
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            db = new CmpContext(
            VcsCmpConnectionstring.GetCMPConnectionString(this.Request));
        }
    }
```